# group by xml document by child element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have the following xml. It is a set of record parent node containing identifiers, quantity and category.

```
<Data>
<record>
    <identifier>1000</identifier>
    <category>B</category>
    <quantity>90.00</quantity>
</record>
<record>
    <identifier>1000</identifier>
    <category>B</category>
    <quantity>50.00</quantity>
</record>
<record>
    <identifier>1001</identifier>
    <category>B</category>
    <quantity>13.00</quantity>
</record>
<record>
    <identifier>1002</identifier>
    <category>B</category>
    <quantity>100.00</quantity>
</record>
```

I need to group by the record element by the child "identifier".
The excpected output is this.

```
<Data>
<records>
    <record>
        <identifier>1000</identifier>
        <category>B</category>
        <quantity>90.00</quantity>
    </record>
    <record>
        <identifier>1000</identifier>
        <category>B</category>
        <quantity>50.00</quantity>
    </record>
</records>
<records>
    <record>
        <identifier>1001</identifier>
        <category>B</category>
        <quantity>13.00</quantity>
    </record>
</records>
<records>
    <record>
        <identifier>1002</identifier>
        <category>B</category>
        <quantity>100.00</quantity>
    </record>
</records>
```

I'm using this xslt but it's not working neither at grouping level.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="Data">
    <Data>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="record" group-by="identifier">
            <records>
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*" />
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </records>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Data>
</xsl:template>
```

How can I fix it to make it work?

Comment: I tried changing xslt-2.0 but I got an error while executing it.

Comment: @JamesTaylor Which is the error message?

Comment: Unable to generate the XML document using the provided XML/XSL input. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 20; XML version "2.0" is not supported, only XML 1.0 is supported

Comment: You have put the "2.0" version into the XML declaration. Like `<?xml version="2.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. Don't.

Comment: It doesn't work..

Comment: The processor supports xslt 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you show can be achieved by slightly adjusting (and simplifying) your stylesheet to:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <Data>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="record" group-by="identifier">
            <records>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
            </records>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Data>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncnu9B8/1

Comment: There's a typo at line 8 (records/record -> record). After fixing it, it works. Thank you.